# Vertically Centering within an element

Tags: css, sass, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I have an `<li>` which is constrained in width and the height is set to an aspect ratio of 1:1.

I then have an element inside which is positioned absolutely with a 100% width and height. I then add an icon font to the :before pseudo element. How can I vertically center that pseudo element?

My code is:

```
li
  +span-columns(1, 6)

  a
    +border-radius(50%)
    display: block
    position: relative
    width: 100%
    border: 5px solid $bright-blue
    border: remCalc(5px) solid $bright-blue

    &:before
      padding-top: 100%
      content: ''
      display: block

    span
      display: block
      position: absolute
      top: 0
      left: 0
      width: 100%
      height: 100%

      &:before
        // Content is added via the style for data-icon
        display: inline-block
        min-height: 100%
        vertical-align: middle
        width: 100%
        color: $white
        font-size: 32px
        text-align: center
        outline: 1px solid red
```

A pic of the problem. The red outline is on the span:before

[image: Pic of issue]

COMPILED OUTPUT:

```
li {
  width: 150px;
}

li  a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

li a:before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

li a span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

li a span:before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-family: 'IconFont';
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Since your question is about CSS (and not about getting Sass to generate the CSS you need), it would be more useful to provide the compiled CSS (and a demo!).

Comment: I can't directly get the compiled output at the moment but it's super easy to convert. Will update OP now for you. Can't provide demo for time being unfortunately.

Comment: Added compiled output for you. The question is basically how can I vertically align the text (icon font text string) inside it's container.

Comment: Did you try *any* [vertical alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+vertical+align+text) techniques?

Comment: Yes I did but none would work.

Comment: I would use the display: inline-block and vertical align trick but the issue is line height. The height of the containing element changes therefore I have no way to know what the line height should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to solve this with top padding like so:

```
$half-width: space(1, 6) / 2
$half-font: remCalc(33px) / 2
$border-widths: remCalc(5px)
+rem(padding-top, $half-width - $half-font - $border-widths)
```

That gives me custom top padding in rems depending on the width of the circle at the time and it scales perfectly when the body font size is increased or decreased.

Answer (score 0):

I'v created a fiddle with a solution for you.

**Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/h3e2G/

your span is called `Content` in my fiddle, and I've add a new span called `Centerer`.
also, I centered some text in the layout, but you can change it back to your logo without noticing any differnce.

the main ideads are:

1. fix the `height` of the `li` (you already fixed the `width`, and if it should be a circle, I dont see a problem with also fixing the height).
2. lossing the `relative` and `ablsolute` way
3. instead of centering the text inside the span (while the span was `height:100%`), we center the span inside his holder.

Comment: I appreciate the fiddle. Unfortunatley I cannot fix the height of the circle as I am using this trick to get perfectly 1:1 width:height ratio circles: http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfdhg

The width of the circles is based on 2 columns of my Susy grid which can change dependent upon media queries. So it's ultra flexible. That's the idea anyway.

Comment: the code that generate the width for your li can't generate the same height? (as you can see, you have a fixed width of 150px)

Comment: That width actually should be a percentage set by Compass Susy, my mistake it transcribing the Sass manually to CSS. So therefore cannot generate the same height.